# How to delay second fragment until the first loads the data in ViewPager?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 2 fragments in view pager.They both start to make network requests at the same time.I want to speed up first fragment by delaying second until the first loads the data.How can i do that? Im coding in java.

Edit:
When both fragments loads the data it takes additional 2 seconds to finish loading first fragment compared to when i make network request only with first fragment(when testing) because view pager loads both tabs at the same time.

Edit2:
found same question at: [link](https://community.commonsware.com/t/how-to-load-data-only-for-current-fragment-in-viewpager/288/3)
One answer suggests creating interface for the first fragment.

```
interface TabView {
fun prepareTab()
fun onTabOpened()
fun onTabClosed()
 }
```

Problem is i cant use interfaces because my first tab uses root fragment  from example that ive found here:  [link](https://github.com/danilao/fragments-viewpager-example)

Edit3: my network request in second fragment: [Implementation of network bound resource](https://github.com/Aero51/Movie-Database/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/aero51/moviedatabase/repository/networkboundresources/EpgChannelsNetworkBoundResource.java)

Comment: You can easily delay the second fragments network request until the second fragment is visible if that is what you are after? or if you want to start the second set of networks request as soon as have completed the first you probably want to separate the loaded data from the Fragments in to something like a ViewModel.

Comment: `ViewPager` by default loads max 3 fragments: one that is currently shown and one on each side of the presented fragment if any. So given only two fragments, your second fragment will load each time anyway. You will have to implement your custom solution to avoid triggering both fragments network calls. Consider using `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to determine which fragment is shown and decide which one should trigger its network calls.

Comment: You can do that through their activity/fragment that holds the `ViewPager`, you can have listener in the first fragment that is implemented by activity, when the fragment loads the data, the callback is called at the activity, and at this time the activity can trigger the second fragment network request

Comment: @Andrew  im already using separate view models and repositories for each fragment that fetches the data, inserts it  to db and then live data observers triggers ui change.I dont want to start network request in second fragment when its visible(when user swipes to tab 2) because that will be bad user experience, user will need to wait additional few seconds...

Comment: @Jenea Vranceanu  "loads" is a bad term, if you are not using an old/depreciated version of Viewpager it will only bring the non visible fragments up to started state and only resume them when visible, therefore you have a chance in `onResume` to do things only when a Fragment is made the one visible one BUT this is not what Nikola wants

Comment: Without see some code on exactly how you do your network request it is difficult to answer, You could do the first Fragements network requests in an AsyncTask and then in the `postexecute` trigger a second AsyncTask task to do the second batch or you could be using `DownloadManager` and then you could wait for broadcast to start the second batch.

Comment: An alternative to interfaces is a shared viewmodel for communicating between fragments (there are other methods as well) see https://androidwave.com/fragment-communication-using-viewmodel/ for example. And then you set a flag in the shared viewmodel in `onChanged` of Fragment1 and then Fragment2 observes this flag in the shared viewmodel and does not `registerLiveDataObservers();` until is in the the right state to say Fragment1 has loaded it's data (data has size > 0 ) PS the link to the code that you have removed was very helpful in understanding your problem

Comment: @Andrew could you write it as answer so i can accept it.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to interfaces is a shared viewmodel for communicating between fragments (there are other methods as well) see [androidwave.com/fragment-communication-using-viewmodel](https://androidwave.com/fragment-communication-using-viewmodel) for example.

You would then you set a flag in the shared viewmodel in `onChanged` of the LiveData observer of Fragment1 and then in Fragment2 observes this flag in the shared viewmodel and does not `registerLiveDataObservers();` until is in the the right state to say Fragment1 has loaded it's data (data has size > 0 )

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: ive used runnable to delay registering of observers in my second fragment.Im sure there are better solutions so i will not yet accept this.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
      registerLiveDataObservers();
        }
    }, 2000);  //delay for 2 seconds
```

Im using live data as retrofit response so it works well with db+network